# UIPickerView Not getting reloaded

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, uipickerview

I'm using a UIPickerView in my sample app and I've got this problem that it doesn't reload the data except the first row. Ive actually coded to assign the first row of the picker independently but the other rows are loaded with the array. The values of the UIPickerView should reload every time the user presses a button but except the first row none of the values change as intended to I'm not able to figure out where I'm going wrong. Below is my code

```
//PickerView Code....
 - (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    return 1;
}
else if (pickerView.tag == 2)
{
    return 1;
}
return 0;
 }
  - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    return [self.CityList count];
}
else
{
    return [self.KmArray count];
}
return 0;
  }


 -(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
return [self.CityList objectAtIndex:row];
 }

    - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
  {
if (pickerView.tag == 1) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    // label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:20];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = self.CityList[row];
    return label;
}
else if (pickerView.tag == 2)
{

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pickerView.frame.size.width, 44)];
    // label.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:20];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    if (row == 0) {
        if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Chennai"])
        {
            __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.8 Km"];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"              "];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"25.00"];
            label.text = lbl1;
            return label;
        }
        else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Banglore"])
        {
            __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.9 Km"];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"              "];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"25.00"];
            label.text = lbl1;
            return label;
        }
        else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Delhi"])
        {
            __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"2.0 Km"];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"              "];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"25.00"];
            label.text = lbl1;
            return label;
        }
        else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Mumbai"])
        {
            __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.5 Km"];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"              "];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"15.00"];
            label.text = lbl1;
            return label;
        }
        else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Puducherry"])
        {
            __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.8 Km"];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"              "];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"25.00"];
            label.text = lbl1;
            return label;
        }
        else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Pune"])
        {
            __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.5 Km"];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"              "];
            lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"17.00"];
            label.text = lbl1;
            return label;
        }
    }
    else
    {
    __weak NSString *lbl1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.KmArray[row]];
    lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:@"              "];
    lbl1 = [lbl1 stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", self.fareArray[row]]];
    label.text = lbl1;
    return label;
    }
}
return 0;
}
  - (IBAction)GetFare:(id)sender
   {
[self.ScrollView setAlpha:1];
NSInteger row = [_SelectCity selectedRowInComponent:0];
self.currentCity = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", [_CityList objectAtIndex:row]];
NSLog(@"Selected city is %@", _currentCity);
[self populatePickerArray];
[_FareList reloadAllComponents];
}
  -(void)populatePickerArray
{
float z=0.0, x = 0.0, ch = 25.0, mu = 15, pu = 17;
float y = 0.0, chd = 1.9, del = 2.1, mud = 1.6, blore = 2.0, pud = 1.6, pudd = 1.9;
if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Chennai"])
{
    x = ch;
    y = chd;
    z = 1.2;
    [self.FareList reloadAllComponents];
}
else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Banglore"])
{
    x = ch ;
    y = blore;
    z = 1.3;
    [self.FareList reloadAllComponents];

}
else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Delhi"])
{
    x = ch ;
    y = del;
    z = 0.8;
    [self.FareList reloadAllComponents];

}
else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Mumbai"])
{
    x = mu ;
    y = mud;
    z = 1.0;
    [self.FareList reloadAllComponents];

}
else if ([_currentCity isEqual:@"Pune"])
{
    x = pu ;
    y = pud;
    z = 1.16;
    [self.FareList reloadAllComponents];

}
else
{
    x = ch;
    y = pudd;
    z = 1.5;
    [self.FareList reloadAllComponents];
}
float i = x;
for (float weight = y; weight <= 25.01; weight = weight + 0.1)
{
    i = i + z;
    //[_KmArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:weight]];
    NSString *weightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.1f Km", weight];
    [_KmArray addObject:weightString];
    NSString *fareString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f", i];
    [_fareArray addObject:fareString];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure populatePickerArray is called and immediately after call `reloadAllComponents` on **both** your picker views.

Apart from this, your code is messy and redundant. You should consider creating a separate object for your picker view to make the code more readable.

Please note that the convention is that variables do not start with uppercase letters. Thus, `cityList`, not `CityList`. Uppercase initials are reserved for classes and some constants.

Comment: everything works fine with the first pickerView…the problem is only with the second pickerView and thanks for the correction on the naming conventions and code readability ll surely work on that….Even-though the realoadAllComponents is called immediately it docent work… :(

Comment: That means that you have not updated the array responsible for the second picker view. Set a breakpoint and check.